# Compilation OgreBullet among VS 2008 SP1

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

Windows 7 x64
Ogre 1.8.1
bullet 2.76

When I try to compile the project OgreBullet, I get this error:

```
error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Performing Post-Build Event..."  Dynamics_Demos
```

Runtime Library - /MDd

and using bullet 2.81:

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc90-mt-sgd-1_49.lib'    Dynamics_Demos
```

Runtime Library - /MTd

What could be the problem?

I apologize for my English...

Comment: did you set the directory for **libboost_thread-vc90-mt-sgd-1_49.lib** in Visual studio

Comment: I do not have this library

Comment: I have a boost but there is no such library, is:
libboost_date_time-vc90-mt-1_49
libboost_date_time-vc90-mt-gd-1_49
libboost_thread-vc90-mt-1_49
libboost_thread-vc90-mt-gd-1_49

Comment: try change ur project to /MDd for dynamic linking, then change the require lib to use gd instead of sgd.

Comment: if so then it gives an error at the library ConvexDecomposition and when using gd instead sgd too many errors

Comment: well then you gotta get the sgd lib, consult boost installation guide on how to get it.

Comment: Thanks, I think it will be easier to look towards an older bullet

Comment: find what to do to correct a mistake when use bullets version 2.76

Dynamics_Demos->Properties->Configuration Properties->Build Events->Post-Build Event->Command Line

delete or edit